# Can you construct $\mathbb{R}^1$ from $\mathbb{R}$ using the cartesian product? If not, how is $\mathbb{R}^1$ constructed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you construct $\mathbb{R}^1$ from $\mathbb{R}$ using the cartesian product? If not, how is  $\mathbb{R}^1$ constructed?

I'm having this doubt, I really don't know how to answer this (this is not an exercise, just a conceptual doubt I had).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @copper.hat  1-coordinate vectors live in the first one and scalars in the other.

Comment: They are isomorphic. The first are all functions $\{1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the second $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: 1-coordinate vectors are the same as scalars as far as I know

Comment: @slinshady: There is a formal distinction, but in practice there is rarely if ever a reason to make it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What is that formal distinction: how do you define a 1-dimensional vector vs a scalar?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: The former is a set of functions from a one-element domain to $\Bbb R$. I would make the domain $\{0\}$, but **copper.hat**’s $\{1\}$ is also a possible choice.

Comment: $\mathbb R^1$ is contructed from the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb R^n$ ($n>1$) is constructed from $\mathbb R^1$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm sorry, but what do you mean by $\{0\} \longrightarrow
\mathbb{R}$. Function's whose domain is the number $0$? Why?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Functions whose domain is the set $\{0\}$. There is one such function for each real number; e.g., $\{\langle 0,\pi\rangle\}$ is the function that sends $0$ to the number $\pi$. One standard construction of $X^n$ is as the set of all functions from $n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ to $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $(a,b)$ to be the set $\{a, \{a,b\}\}$, and define $A \times B$ to be the set $\{ (x, y) : x \in A \land y \in B \}$. Then $\mathbb{R} \times \emptyset = \emptyset$, and $\mathbb{R} \times A$ for any non empty set at results in a set of ordered pairs. This begs the question, is $\mathbb{R}^1$ a set of ordered pairs? I would say not, as this could make $\mathbb{R}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, which can't be right. So using this definition I would say the answer to your question is negative. Perhaps we could just say $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^1$ which is agreeable to many exponentiation rules.

However, if we use functions from an ordinal to some set $A$ to represent tuples of elements of $A$ of any size, then $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the set of functions from $\{\emptyset\} \to \mathbb{R}$. If a function $f : A \to B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ such that $\forall a \in A \exists! b \in B (a,b) \in f$, then $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $\{ \{\emptyset\} \times \{r\} : r \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which uses the cartesian product in its definition, and is quite distinct from plain old $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: http://begthequestion.info/ :-)